# How to change type of information for a Title column in SharePoint MOSS 2007 List?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I created a calendar in SharePoint MOSS 2007 that is connected to my Outlook. I added a custom column “Person” to this list and the type of information in this column is:  Person or Group.  In SharePoint I can hide Title column and in Calendar View show this Person field as Month View Title. So I can see on the calendar who is working that day. Problem is in Outlook. It seems like Outlook doesn’t know a thing about custom fields. In Outlook I can see only Title and few other fields. I could rename Title field to Person, but I can’t change type of information that it contains. By default it is text field and no way to change it to Person or Group.

If I could change those “default” column types, then I think my problem would be solved. I know it is possible. I created a custom list, but this list has also those “sticky” Title, Created By and Modified By columns that can’t be changed or removed. Maybe I have to create a custom list with some other program or code? Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Title Column is a **necessary evil**.

In Outlook, Calendars (as of my tests) only show Title and Location.

One solution (be that javascript or .NET) is to, by the time the user clicks the "OK" button on the NewForm and EditForm, you copy the content in the Person or Group column to the end of the (Person Name) location field, so it will show up as:

> **Title**; Location (Person)

.. in your monthly view.

Comment: Not in your calendar, your limitations sets the rules. We are not discussing sharepoint in a general sense.